# Нужно в объект засунуть процентное значение ключа

Tags: javascript, svg-animation, gsap

У меня есть вот такой код

```
gsap.to('.planet-man', {
    duration: 2,
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '.we-do',
        start: 'top 25%',
        end: '70% 50%',
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        toggleActions: 'reverse',
    },
    motionPath: {
        path: [
            {x: -30, y: 35},
            {x: -180, y: 70},
            {x: -180, y: 150},
            {x: -340, y: 250},
            {x: -410, y: 275},
            {x: -150, y: 310},
            {x: -500, y: 350},
            {x: -185, y: 600},
            {x: -270, y: 700},
            {x: -100, y: 820},
        ],
    }
});
```

Это для движения по скролу, но так как перемещение идет по пикселям - оно статично. Мне нужно X - задать процентное значение что бы таким образом оптимизировать его под многие экраны а не только под свой. Возможно мне подойдет функция которая динамически будет измерять ширину моего экрана и с подставление туда моих значений X, в соответствии с моим экраном к остальным.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.second-area').css('width', function () {
        const value = $('.second-area').css('width');
        console.log(value);
        // return value + "px";
    });
});
```

Вопрос как мне это сделать?
( Код с window.resize не обязателен, это просто то что у меня есть на данный момент. Важно лишь одно иксу, дать процентное значение. )

Comment: Что такое `gsap`?

Comment: Библиотека для анимации по скролу

Comment: И эта библиотека не поддерживает процентное указание x и y? Сложно понять что у Вас движется и по какому "холсту". Если что-то движется не по бесконечному "холсту", то у этого должно быть процентное значение и в таком случае можно создать метод, который будет принимать на "вход" процентные значения, а выдавать абсолютные в пикселах для конкретного разрешения/размера "холста". Т.е. верхний правый угол x: 100%, y: 0%, нижний левый угол x: 0%, y: 100% (это если координаты с верхнего левого угла считать).

Comment: https://testukas.versija.info/
Вот пример. Это мой сайт. Космонавт должен пролететь с правого верхнего к левому нижнему углу блока, у меня он пролетает идеально на МОЕМ, экране, но проблема в том что это только на моем. Да мне нужна какая то функция которая будет мне выдавать в значение Х, проценты, но увы я этого не знаю, и прошу помочь, что это за функция должна быть? Как мне её написать?

Comment: Тут, скорее всего к CSS нужно обратиться, но как мне это представляется... Вашего комонавта Вы можете поместить в контейнер с аболютным позиционированием, а в CSS стилях прописать анимацию и никакая библиотека для этого не понадобится. Например как показано здесь: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: Да, но эта анимация должна зависить от скрола, а не быть статичной или еще какой то.

Comment: С CSS можно сделать так, чтоб это зависело от scrolla.

Comment: Как? И тогда мне не нужно получается будет с этой проблемой возится ( про проценты ) ? Дайте пожалуйста какую то наводящую информацию.

Comment: Я же написал уже Вам, что на мой взгляд это можно реализовать с помощью анимации на CSS. И ссылку дал, т.е. в какую сторону смотреть. На CSS анимацию можно сделать и "одноразовой" и цикличной. Создайте в HTML контейнер, поместите в него Вашего Армстронга и попробуйте. Если возникнут трудности, то создадите новый вопрос уже с конкретной проблемой и кодом, который можно будет здесь воспроизвести в виджете кода. P.S.: не совсем понимаю какая у Вас проблема со скролом? Космонавт должен двигаться относительно чего? DIV'а, документа, ... ?

Comment: Относительно дива. Хорошо я попробую спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все элементарно указать в процентах можно написав не просто  `x:` а  `xPercent: 10` . Это будет +10 процентов по x. Или же просто `x: '25%'`что так же будет значить вправо на 25%. Все равно всем спасибо.